# What are the red waves around fighters?

Tags: grappler-baki

In the anime *Baki the Grappler*, there are several scenes in the 1st and 2nd season when there is a bit of a staredown and these reddish waves emanate from their bodies when two characters are about to fight.

What are these red waves?

Comment: @AshishGupta how did you get that tag? When I tried using that tag it said I needed 150 reputation to make a new tag. But it already exists and I couldn't use it. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: No. I have 150 reputation and hence was able to created that tag. It wasn't there before this question. You can provide a tag guidance [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1198) which will then be approved by someone who has 1.5k reputation.

Comment: Use the [tag:retag] tag if you can't find the tag you're looking for.

Comment: I see well @AshishGupta is there a way for you to add a tag for "bakithegrappler"? Since grappler-baki is the title of the manga and my question is about the anime which has the "Baki the grappler" title?  I'll also post the retag tag.

Comment: @Hikari I posted that tag because the title [here](http://myanimelist.net/anime/287/Grappler_Baki_(TV)) said that Baki The Grappler is the English name of the anime. Anyway, someone has already suggested a tag synonym for grappler-baki as baki-the-grappler and I don't have sufficient reputation to accept or even suggest that. It'll be dealt by users having more than 1.5k reputation.

Comment: @Hikari For future reference, if you type in "baki-the" into the tag field (when it's empty), it'll auto-suggest "grappler-baki", since "baki-the-grappler" is already marked as a synonym for [grappler-baki](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/grappler-baki/synonyms).

Comment: It could be their aura.lol.. :D

Comment: @bot It could be that's something that I considered but it seems like they would have spoken on it more in the anime or at least given sort of a description. I seen aura plenty of times in other work. But in this series it's never talked about. Most I've seen is it described as a feeling. But nothing outside of that.

Comment: @KazRodgers _could be_ the representation of the thirst of blood and fight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the manga, I have determined that this is the artist's way of depicting each fighter's aura or bloodlust.

It's not for a specific fighter or occasion and appears constantly throughout the anime and manga.